# Nginx Rewrite 414-URI Too Large

Tags: cakephp, nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to setup CakePHP on an nginx server. [Following their blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html) on setting up URL rewriting for nginx, I ended up with this in my sites-available/default file:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name localhost;
    rewrite ^(.*) localhost$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name localhost;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/StudentRecords/webroot;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

/usr/share/nginx/html/StudentRecords/ is the top directory for my CakePHP app.

When I go to the URL localhost, it shows me the default "Welcom to nginx" page. If I try to go to localhost/StudentRecords/webroot, I get a 414 error, and end up with a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/localhost/StudentRecords/webroot/
```

I'm having trouble understanding why the server root doesn't point to StudentRecords/webroot, and why my url is multiplying like that.

Comment: The only server block used for that request is the first one. It should be obvious why that's a redirect loop since the only thing it does is redirect to itself changing the _path_ to be prefixed by 'localhost'

Comment: Thanks. I guess I wasn't looking closely enough at the rewrite line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `rewrite ^(.*) localhost$1 permanent;` line (and first code block) was unnecessary. Removing the first block, as well as clearing my browser cache has resolved both issues.

Answer (score 1):

just remove the first server block